# How to pass an Object to JSP in jsp:include or c:set

Tags: html, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

When I tried to send Object through jsp:param, it was sent as String.
eg:

```
<jsp:include page="Page1.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="key" value="${Object1}"/>
</jsp:include>

<jsp:include page="Page1.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="key" value="${Object2}"/>
</jsp:include>
```

So I tried using,

```
<c:set var="param" value="${Object1}" scope="request" />
<jsp:include page="Page1.jsp"/>

<c:set var="param" value="${Object2}" scope="request" />
<jsp:include page="Page1.jsp"/>
```

This is Page1.jsp:

```
<c:out value="${param.data}"/>
<jsp:include page="Page2.jsp"/>
<c:out value="${param.value}"/>
```

O/P

```
object1data
object1value
object2data
object1value
```

The values for the first time before calling other jsp page is unique. But the next value is overridden by the first objects content.Why so?

Answer (score 0):

Actullay in Page2.jsp, the same variable was declared again with Object1 values with request scope.
So the values were overridden.

Page2.jsp:

```
<c:set var="param" value="${Object1}" scope="request" />
{page2 functionality}
```

Since the same key param was set again the value was overridden in all places after calling the file.